# Open current folder in atom from git-bash (windows 7)

Tags: git, atom-editor, git-bash

I would like to know if there is a way to open the current folder in the atom with the git-bash console (windows 7). So far, I used the [instructions](https://cmiaral.com/how-to-open-atom-in-git-bash-windows-10/). After entering command:

`atom .`

atom opens the folder:

*C:...\atom\app-1.24.1*

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an alias (I am using Sublime Text as an example)

```
alias sublime ='/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe'
cd mydirectory // cd into the dir
sublime . // Open current folder in sublime
```

For one time

```
/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe .
```

You can reuse the above but using the location of Atom on your machine. Be sure to add the `.exe` in the path of the Atom

*Note: the `\` is escaping the spaces in the path. If there is a space in the path, it needs to be escaped*

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same result as before, but now atom opens the _C:...\atom\app-1.25.0_ folder

Comment: @MathewKirmuć can you share the exact command you are running?